# Как вывести данные из файла формата CSV на сайте?

Tags: javascript, html, файлы

Как с помощью JavaScript можно прочитать содержимое файла в формате, сходном с `*.csv` и вывести полученные данные в таблицу, сверстанную, например, с использованием Bootstrap?

Comment: никак. JS не имеет доступа к файловой системе ПК. Как вариант можно выбрать вайл в `input type="file"` и считать его как текст. Это такое себе.

Comment: bootstrap и html - это инструменты для верстки, и они не предоставляют возможности вывода с файла. Вам нужен `js`

Comment: @Tsyklop есть вариант подключение файла через `src`

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц каким это образом?

Comment: @Максим да при чем тут bootstrap? это всего лишь инструмент. написали же выше... ппц

Comment: А я делал на js) пинганите меня вечером если ответ не напишу

Comment: @Tsyklop  не соглашусь. Прочитать локальные файлы можно, но в случае с XLS это будет конечно проблематично, а вот для CSV пойдёт: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ На стороне клиента можно даже MD5 хеш вычислять :)

Comment: Когда-то, давным-давно, баловался: https://jsfiddle.net/XelaNimed/q5AZk/

Comment: Всем спасибо  за  ответы. Не  буду создавать новую  тему,  вопрос  - на сколько реально сделать, что бы   в выводе  таблицы из  CSV - оставались рабочие  ссылки  в столбцах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файлы в формате `*.csv` - это текстовые файлы и они читаются при помощи AJAX, если иное не запрещено настройками сервера:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  fetch('test.csv')
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.text();
      }
      throw new Error('Не удалось загрузить файл.');
    }).then(function(text) {
      renderTable(text);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error('Произошла ошибка при попытке отобразить файл: ' + error.message);
    });
});
```

---

Ниже небольшой пример чтения и отрисовки таблицы при выборе пользователем файла из `input`-а с атрибутом `type="file"`. В качестве разделителя строк в таблице выбраны переносы, а ячеек - `;`. Допустимое расширение - `*.csv`.

```js
// Элемент для выбора файлов.
const INPUT = document.querySelector('input[name="readable"]');
// Элемент для вывода сгенерированной таблицы.
const PREVIEW = document.querySelector('#preview');
// Регулярное выражение для проверки расширения файла.
const REGEX = new RegExp('(.*?)\.(csv)$', 'i');

// Функция, отрабатывающая при выборе файла.
function handleFile(event) {
  // Выбираем первый файл из списка файлов.
  const file = event.target.files[0];

  // Если файл выбран и его расширение допустимо,
  // то читаем его содержимое и отправляем
  // в функцию отрисовки таблицы.
  if (file && REGEX.test(file.name)) {
    // Создаем экземпляр объекта.
    const reader = new FileReader();

    // Чтение файла асинхронное, поэтому
    // создание таблицы привязываем к событию `load`,
    // которое срабатывает при успешном завершении операции чтения.
    reader.onload = (e) => renderTable(e.target.result);

    // Читаем содержимое как текстовый файл.
    reader.readAsText(file);
  } else {
    // Мизерная обработка ошибок.
    alert('Файл не выбран либо его формат не поддерживается.');
    event.target.value = '';
  }
}

// Функция отрисовки таблицы.
function renderTable(data) {
  // Предварительно создадим элементы,
  // отвечающие за каркас таблицы.
  let table = document.createElement('table');
  let thead = document.createElement('thead');
  let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

  // Добавим класс к таблице.
  table.classList.add('table');

  // Разбиваем входящие данные построчно.
  // Разделитель - перенос строки.
  // Перебираем полученный массив строк.
  data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/)
    .forEach(function(row, index) {
      // Создадим элемент строки для таблицы.
      let trow = document.createElement('tr');

      // Разбиваем каждую строку на ячейку.
      // Разделитель - точка с запятой.
      // Перебираем полученный массив будущих ячеек.
      row.split(/;/).forEach(function(cell) {
        // Создадим элемент ячейки для таблицы.
        let tcell = document.createElement(index > 0 ? 'td' : 'th');
        // Заполним содержимое ячейки.
        tcell.textContent = cell;
        // Добавляем ячейку к родительской строке.
        trow.appendChild(tcell);
      });

      // Добавляем строку к родительскому элементу.
      // Если индекс строки больше нуля,
      // то родительский элемент - `tbody`,
      // в противном случае- `thead`.
      index > 0 ? tbody.appendChild(trow) : thead.appendChild(trow);
    });

  // Добавляем заголовок таблицы к родительскому элементу.
  table.appendChild(thead);
  // Добавляем тело таблицы к родительскому элементу.
  table.appendChild(tbody);

  // Очищаем элемент для вывода таблицы.
  PREVIEW.innerHTML = '';
  // Добавляем саму таблицу к родительскому элементу.
  PREVIEW.appendChild(table);
}

// Регистрируем функцию обработчика события `change`,
// срабатывающего при изменении элемента выбора файла.
INPUT.addEventListener('change', handleFile);
```

```html
<input type="file" name="readable" accept=".csv" />

<div id="preview"></div>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

---

**PS** Лучше воспользоваться готовыми библиотеками.