# Как правильно прочитать статичный файл и занести каждую строку в массив в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, файлы, blob

Есть большой файл с текстом:

***file.txt***

```
first
second
third
...
```

Нужно прочесть из него все строки и занести их в массив, использую клиентский JavaScript. Я пробовал сделать так:

```
const LOCAL_RESOURCE = new File([], './file.txt');

window.onload = function() {
    readLines(LOCAL_RESOURCE);
}

function readLines(file) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(obj) {
        var FileContent = obj.target.result;
        parseContent(FileContent);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

function parseContent(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

Но была выведена пустая строка. Как правильно инициализировать Blob и записать каждую строку в массив?

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/992626/256824

Comment: А где данный файл находится? На клиенте или на сервере?